# specify biased y samples for 3d Plotting in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am working to plot this 3d graph

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,colormap={blackwhite}{[5pt]
        rgb255(300pt)=(0,0,200);
        rgb255(500pt)=(255,255,100);
        rgb255(700pt)=(200,0,0)
    },
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={fn(\x,\y,\n)=2*(-1)^(\n-1)*sin(\n*pi*\x)*sinh(\n*pi*\y)/(\n*pi*sinh(2*\n*pi));
u(\x,\y)=fn(\x,\y,1)+fn(\x,\y,2)+fn(\x,\y,3)+fn(\x,\y,4)+fn(\x,\y,5)+fn(\x,\y,6);}]
    \begin{axis}[view={25}{30},zmin=0,zmax=1.2,trig format plots=rad]
        \addplot3[surf,samples=20,samples y=40,domain=0:1,y domain=0:2,point meta min=0,point meta max=1] {u(\x,\y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Most of the graph is flat at zero so I don't care for the y sampling there but from $1.5\leq y\leq2$ I would like to have more samples there.

I know of the sample at function for the domain $(x)$, but cannot find any information on how to adjust the plot like this for the $y$ variable as well.

Ideally I would like to be able to specify

```
samples y at={0,.1,...,1.5,1.505,1.51,...,2}
```

Comment: Try with this changes in the domain; domain=0.7:1,y domain=1.3:2

Comment: I actually need the entire domain for both variables as these are plots for PDE's and I need to show the entire boundary for the function.